# Euler's theorem and $Z_p^*$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, totient-function

Euler's theorem states that for x and p coprime, $x^{\phi(p)}\equiv1 \bmod p$, does it mean that $x$ has the order $\phi(p)$ in $Z_p^*$? I checked it manually for $x=2$ and it held for some cases. How would one prove or disprove that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This theorem only says that $\text{ord}_p(x)$ must divides $\phi(p)$.

For the **counter-example** let $p=7$ and let $x=2$;
but notice that 
$\text{ord}_7(2)= 3$. 
$$
2^3 \overset{7}{\equiv}1 
\ \ 
\text{and} 
\ \
2^2 \overset{7}{\ncong}1 
\ \ 
\text{and} 
\ \
2^1 \overset{7}{\ncong}1 .$$